# Grab all Mozilla Firefox's open tabs urls

Tags: vba, url, firefox

I know that this is an annoying question because, in a way or another, there are lots of tries but no satisfactory solutions. Until now, anyway.

Is there someone who have a VBA code able to grab the Mozilla's tabs links?

Please, give me almost some code to work with.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], as well as [mcve].  The above is a request for work not a specific programming problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the information. I read the "How to ask" part before my question, of course, but the point is that I don't have any code to present, because simply I havent' find anything looking around as in the web as in SO, and I have no idea how to approach the problem. I found some codes, but they are written in .net, or in "autohotkey" code, and I'm not interest at all in them (actually, I can't use them in my Excel sheets). Unfortunately, I'm despairing to find a way to accomplish this task. Probably, There's no way at all...

Comment: I understand it can very frustrating. Can you translate the .net code?

Comment: Unfortunately no... and I'm not sure everything could be translated, but I'm mostly an absolute beginner in  .net code. Anyway, here there's an example: [basic links](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca257f22-115e-43f2-a28d-c806c81061b7/get-url-of-ie-firefox-and-chrome-brower?forum=vbgeneral). Maybe someone could take inspirations for a VBA code. .

Answer (score 0):

I have never though of this before!  This seems like kind of a weird question, but I'm somewhat intrigued by this anyway.  Check out the video demo from the uRL below, and see is it gives you what you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7kJ6mp53p4

Basically, Tools > Options > Use Current Pages (this will give you all URLs in all tabs).  Then, copy/paste wot Word, parse based on '|' character (i.e., Find = '|'; Replace = '^p').  Now, you should have everything you need, and you don't even touch a single line of VBA.

Also, here is a VBA solution, using IE.  I think it's going to be hard to control Mozilla from Excel.  Since IE and Excel are both in the Microsoft family, they integrate very well.  Other technologies, outside of the Microsoft family, don't always integrate as nicely.

```
Sub getALLBrowsers()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    i = 2

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ow In objAllWindows
        If (InStr(1, ow, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare)) Then
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = ow
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i) = ow.Hwnd
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = ow.Document.Title
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i) = ow.locationURL
            i = i + 1
            'MsgBox ow.Hwnd & "  " & ow & "   " & ow.locationURL & "  " & ow.Document.Title
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think you misunderstood my question. Actually, I need to insert a button somewhere in an Office application like Excel or Access, so pushing it I could grad all the Mozzilla's open tabs copying them for other activities I've planned. Of course, I need a VBA code to do it. By now, I'm copying and pasting the tabs' urls, but this annoy me a lot.

Comment: The routine is simple and useful for windows, but I'm looking for  a code that is flexible enough to get urls from all the pages of all open browers. I saw in the WEB that someone tried using the windows API, but also in this I am a layman.

Answer (score 0):

After working on it a bit, I found a solution. 
Thanks to the advice of a friend, I considered to get the URLs from the **browser history**.
Mozilla save it in a file that always updated with each new website opened in the browser, and the file is locate in the following: "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\", where there is the *default* folder.
Inside there, Mozilla saves history in a file called *places.sqlite*. This a sqlite database with free access (everyone could examines it using «sqlite browser», for example). 
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBJlA.png)

The database is composed of many tables, but the one that interests me is *moz_places*.
[table attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLIrH.png)

The code i wrote follows this idea, so I used Excel and I just retrieve the DB, that contains all the URLs I was looking for.

```
Sub provaSQL()

'SQLite ODBC Driver
Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC  Driver;Database=C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\h6mfz4zy.default\places.sqlite;"

strSQL = "Select * From moz_places order by last_visit_date DESC"

rst.Open strSQL, conn, 1, 1

Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Obviously, you need to install the *sqlite 3 driver* because previously it was already present, but now MS is wary of what is freely accessible ...

Check for the correct root for your Mozilla (it changes depending on the type, on the version etc.).
And check also for the table's name. It could be different, too.

There remains a problem to be solved: in the database there isn't any attribute that indicates whether the tabs are open, so the active URLs in the Firefox browser are not identifiable with this procedure.
As I have to open the tabs in Firefox manually, I solved with an indirect operation (via code): every time I open the browser, I use to start with the Google webpage, so after my research in the WEB opening all the tabs I need, I close Mozilla (using a WEB API code) and all the opened tabs inside there. So I can consider the Google page as the beginning of my session, and all the previous URLs are certain that belong to my research, and I can analyze them. Maybe all this is not necessary, but it is the easiest way I found it.

I add this routine, too, even if you can avoid it.

```
Option Explicit

Global r As Long

Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetClassNameA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Const WM_CLOSE = &H10
Private Const WM_QUIT = &H12

Private Target As String
Public TargetOpen As Boolean

Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long ' {
    Dim WindowText  As String, sMess As String
    Dim windowClass As String * 256
    Dim retVal      As Long
    Dim l           As Long

    On Error GoTo errori
    retVal = GetClassName(hwnd, windowClass, 255)
    windowClass = Left$(windowClass, retVal)
    'Cells(r, 1) = windowClass
    If InStr(1, windowClass, "Mozilla") > 0 Then
        TargetOpen = True
        SendMessage hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0
    End If

    r = r + 1
  '
  ' Return true to indicate that we want to continue
  ' with the enumeration of the windows:
  '
    EnumWindowsProc = True
Exit Function
errori:
sMess = MsgBox("Errore n. " & Err.Number, " - " & Err.Description)
Resume Next
End Function

Sub main()
    r = 1
    Call EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, ByVal 0&)
End Sub
```

Any suggestions or improvements are welcome.